# sapui5 one to many1 relationship

Tags: web-applications, odata, sapui5

I started my first job and was thrown into a sapui5 project without any experience so far, so i think this may be a pretty basic question.

I was given the task to work with 3 tables, lets call them A1,B1 and C1.
A1 has a one to many1 relationship to both B and C. 
How is data binding done in those scenarios? I had no problem in previous tasks with 1..1 relationships, but this gives me a headache.

To be a bit more specific, the task is to do a table(in a xml view) with the "id" from table A1, "name" from B1 and "name1" from C1. In the odata service the navigation looks something like this

```
<NavigationProperty Name="ToB1" Relationship="master.A1_B1_One_Many0" FromRole="A1" ToRole="B1"/>
```

I am out of ideas right now and hope you can give me some helpful hints.
If you need me to specify the question or need any additional information, please ask me, since i dont have much experience with stackoverflow yet

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. After binding "ToB1" i always got an array with was looked like references. When i tried to access propertys via these references it always gave me an error. I had to put an "/" in front of the path in order to access it. This part of my code helped me fixing it. I get the object by looping over the array.

```
oModel.getObject("/" + oObject).name1
```